# Will this statement ever evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript

I'm new-ish to Javascript and need to make a change to this one script. I noticed this line of code that thoroughly confused me, however.

```
function FIValidateForm(aForWhom, aDoNotShowWarning, aFromWhere) 
{
    try 
    {
        PAIWarnings = '';
        var pBlFalg = true;

        if (pBlFalg) 
            pBlFalg = mfpCheckForFISave(aForWhom, aDoNotShowWarning, aFromWhere);

        if (pBlFalg == true)
            pBlFalg = PAIErrors();

        if ((pBlFalg) && (FIValidateForm.arguments.length == 1))
            mfpIFWarnings();

        return pBlFalg;
    }
    catch (err) 
    {
        logError(err, arguments.callee.trace());
    }
}
```

During run time, if I put a breakpoint on that third `if` statement and inspect `FIValidateForm.arguments` I can see an array with 3 items. The first contains a `string`, the second is `null`, and the third is `undefined`. The array still has a length of 3.

Am I correct in assuming that no matter what one were to pass to this method, `FIValidateForm.arguments.length == 1` will always be `false`? Or is there some other value I'm unaware of / alternative way to call this method so that `arguments.length` would equal 1?

Edit: I see JS has an `arguments.length` and a `Function.length`. The latter returns the *expected* number of parameters... So then how does one call a method so that the value would be 1 when the function is defined with 3?

Comment: Try calling the function with just the first argument and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that no matter what one were to pass to this method, FIValidateForm.arguments.length == 1 will always be false?

No, you can make its `FIValidateForm.arguments.length` 1 by doing this:

```
FIValidateForm(justOneArgHere);
```

`arguments` represents the *actual arguments* to the function. (See <sup>1</sup> below about `arguments` vs. `FIValidateForm.arguments`.)

If you want the function's *arity* (the number of formal declared arguments), that's the `FIValidateForm.length` and it doesn't vary.

> So then how does one call a method so that the value would be 1 when the function is defined with 3?

JavaScript doesn't enforce the number of formal arguments at all; you can call your function with no arguments, one argument, or 15. If a formal argument (a declared one, like your `aDoNotShowWarning`) is not supplied, the value it will have within the function call will be `undefined`. If you supply *more* arguments than are declared, they are only accessible (in ES5 and below) via the `arguments` pseudo-array. (In ES2015 and above, you can make your last argument a "rest argument", which means it will be an array of all arguments from that point on.)

---

Example:

```js
function foo(a, b, c) {
  console.log(arguments.length);
  console.log(foo.length);
}
foo(1);
foo(1, 2);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The `arguments` property **of the function** (e.g.,  `FIValidateForm.arguments`) is a non-standard extension to JavaScript, which is expressly deprecated by strict mode (the example above would throw an error in strict mode). Just use the freestanding symbol `arguments`, which is defined for normal functions (as though it were a local variable).

(And in ES2015 or higher, you can avoid using `arguments` at all by using rest notation on your argument declarations instead.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't always be false.

- If you call it as `FIValidateForm()`, then `FIValidateForm.arguments.length === 0`
- If you call it as `FIValidateForm(arg1)`, then `FIValidateForm.arguments.length === 1`
- If you call it as `FIValidateForm(arg1, arg2)`, then `FIValidateForm.arguments.length === 2`
- If you call it as `FIValidateForm(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, then `FIValidateForm.arguments.length === 3`
- And so on

Howver, **do not use `FIValidateForm.arguments`**. It's bad practice and forbidden in strict mode. Use `arguments` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** If you ever call the function with only one argument, `functionName.arguments.length === 1` will be true.

---

Yes, `FIValidateForm.arguments.length` gives you exactly the number of arguments you call `FIValidateForm` with.

Consider this function `f`:

```
function f(first, second) {
  console.log('first argument:', first);
  console.log('second argument:', second);
  console.log('number of arguments:', f.arguments.length);
}
```

and these two cases:

```
// case 1:
f('something');
// prints:
//   first: something
//   second: undefined
//   number of arguments: 1

// case 2:
f('something', undefined);
// prints:
//   first: something
//   second: undefined
//   number of arguments: 2
```

Notice how `undefined` is the "default" value for missing arguments, but unlike an explicit `undefined` argument, a missing argument is not counted in `f.arguments.length`.